# Correct way to add relational data to Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've created two objects in my model, Account and Friend - where 1 Account will have many Friends. I have created these two objects in code also.

I am using a UITableView to show my Accounts (all fine), and using a new UIViewController to add a new record. In the new record I am adding the Account details, and getting friends from an API. When going from the UITableView to the new UIViewController I am creating an empty Account object: UIViewController.account = account;

Now the tricky part. When saving this data I am doing the following:

```
// Configure the new account with information from the form.
[account setUsername:[profileDict objectForKey:@"the_name"]];
[account setPassword:password.text]; // from formfield
[account setCreationDate:[NSDate date]];

// Commit the change.
NSError *error;
if (![account.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"save error");
}

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [account managedObjectContext];

for(NSArray *names in usernameArray) //usernameArray holds my Friends
{

    friend = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [account addReplyAccountsObject:friend];
    [friend setName:[names objectAtIndex:0]];
    [friend setPicUrl:[names objectAtIndex:1]];

    // Commit the change.
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"save error");
    }       
}
```

Now this seems to work - however sometimes my app crashes with a bus error - usually on the device rather than the simulator. Is this the right way to save an Account and many Friends at once? Also - any reason why I would get a bus error? It seems to happen when there are many Friends....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an error in the line:

```
   friend = [NSEntityDescription insertNewOb...
```

You need to declare the type of your variable:

```
   Friend *friend = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObj...
```

(Assuming your Friend class is named `Friend`.)

Also, I wouldn't commit the changes every time around the loop. Make the changes, and then, when you're finished, commit them:

```
for(NSArray *names in usernameArray) //usernameArray holds my Friends
{
   // ...
}

// Commit the change.
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"save error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - friend is declared in my .h file as Friend *friend.

Comment: If you are inserting new friend objects in a loop like that then it is a very bad idea to declare it in your header.  You should be using a local variable for that otherwise `friend` will only reference the last object entered.  Not to mention you are holding a reference to temporary data unnecessarily.

Comment: @mootymoots: Just out of interest, did moving the commit code out of the loop fix the error? Also, as @Marcus S. Zarra comments, setting the same instance variable over and over again is a bad idea—use a local variable instead.